# Bash strings replacement markdown

Tags: html, xml, bash, markdown

Hello there I've got a Markup file where I want to replace some pattern with others:

```
Doing a rapid technical analysis we can consider that radios are working in a magnetic resonance environment use **shortwave** [[66]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortwave_radio) frequencies. Transmitters and receivers are called **radio frequency coils** [[67]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiofrequency_coil) and use **loop antennas** [[68]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_antenna) or **ferrite loop antennas** [[69]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoros).
```

Every time, more than one, that I found a ** text ** I want to replace ** with `<a href=...>` text `</a>` 
The link has to be what fallow between () and I want to eliminate [[]].

Can someone help me with this tarea?

Nice regards,

Comment: Have you considered the `sed` command? What have you tried?

Comment: s/\*\*([A-Za-z_0-9 /\-]*)\*\*/<span class="important">\1<\/span>/g
s/\[\[([0-9]+)\]\]/<a href="" rel="external nofollow">\1<\/a>/g

Comment: You should edit your question and include it there. Otherwise, it's difficult for others to find, and hard to read without stackoverflow mark-up formatting.

Comment: Are you constrained to use particular utilities?  PERL, Python, bash-only, sed, awk, ...?